# Erro ao inflar menu no navigation drawer na versão Nougat e Oreo

Tags: android, material-design

Olá, estou com um problema com o NavigationDrawer do Android nas versões 7 ou superior. Quando eu adiciono o menu atráves do xml, um exception é gerado. Porém, na versão MARSHMALLOW funciona corretamente.

Segue meu código:

activity_livros.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/content_livros" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_livros"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_livros_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_livros.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFF" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.518" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu/activity_livros_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

LivrosActivity.java

```
package br.com.whereit.orvil.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import br.com.whereit.orvil.Adapters.LivrosTabAdapter;
import br.com.whereit.orvil.R;

public class LivrosActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    LivrosTabAdapter livrosTabAdapter;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_livros);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Livros");

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Lendo"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Quero Ler"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Lidos"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        livrosTabAdapter = new LivrosTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        viewPager.setAdapter(livrosTabAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer==null) {
            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        }
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.livros, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if(drawer==null){
            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Exception gerado ao abrir activity

```
01-26 09:19:02.151 25900-25900/br.com.whereit.orvil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: br.com.whereit.orvil, PID: 25900
                                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:302)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:402)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1196)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
01-26 09:19:02.159 25900-25900/br.com.whereit.orvil E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2361)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2083)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1269)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6382)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6146)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 15 to dimension: type=0x1
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:720)
                                                                          at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4213)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:575)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.<init>(LinearLayoutCompat.java:153)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.<init>(ForegroundLinearLayout.java:61)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:94)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:90)
                                                                            ... 68 more
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' tente color isso no gradle

Comment: E faz o famoso clean + rebuild.

Comment: Mas eu estou usando a versão 26 da lib support design           implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Comment: clean + rebuild nao funcionou

Comment: Na linha getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.livros, menu); não achei seu menu com nome menu.xml. No lugar de R.menu.livros deveria ser activity_livros_drawer.xml não?

Comment: Esse outro arquivo de menu refere-se ao menu da toolbar

Comment: seus icones são xml ou png? ("@drawable/ic_menu_send")

Comment: remova o "tools:showIn="navigation_view" do seu xml de menu,

Comment: Leandro eu rodei o projeto aqui apenas comentando o adapter e o setadapter do viewpager. E não deu esse problema, rodou normal.
Tenta comentar e veja se vai rodar normalmente

Comment: @FlipNovid estão em formato xml. Removi "tools:showIn="navigation_view"  do menu e msm assim o erro persisitiu

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro eu comentei a implementação das tabs e do viewpager e o erro continuou

Comment: Eu testei num emulador com a versão Marshmallow e funcionou, porém num device com Nougat e com Oreo o resultado foi a mesma exception.

Comment: Vou testar no 7.0

Comment: Leandro testei no Nougat e também foi normal.

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro Estranto é que quando eu comento a linha que configura o menu no NavigationView, não é gerado nenhuma exception, mesmo com as tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teste no 7.1.1

Neste trecho pode fazer assim:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  if(navigationView.isShown()){
      drawer.closeDrawers();
  }
}
```

E neste aqui:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    drawer.closeDrawers(); //fechar o drawer


    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: tah.. mais qual era o erro?

Comment: Na verdade não tive erro algum, do código que ele postou apenas comentei esse trecho:


    livrosTabAdapter = new 
    LivrosTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    viewPager.setAdapter(livrosTabAdapter);

Comment: Testei no emulador com Android 7.1.1 e continua com o problema. Comentei tudo relacionado a Tabs e ViewPager

Comment: Você pode passar o projeto? Ai tento compilar aqui.

Comment: Ok, vou comitar e passo pro github

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro ttps://github.com/leandroprogramador/Orvil

Comment: Leandro fiz o teste e foi normal, deu um problema que fechou o emulador quando o drawer esta aberto. nesta parte tanto ao selecionar o item e no backpress, pode implementar como eu passei.

Comment: Leandro qual o processador do seu pc? Tenho um amigo que estava tendo problemas com isso, o processador não tinha suporte a instruções que o emulador precisava, você tem algum dispositivo físico que tenha o nougat instalado ?

Comment: @AndersonCanteiro eu testei em dispositivivos fisicos mesmo. Tanto um Motorola X Play com Android 7.1 e um Zenfone 4 com Android 8.0

Comment: Eu implementei o onBackPress e o onNavigationItemSelected e não houve diferença nenhuma.

Comment: Vou testar num dispositivo físico 7.1.1 aqui, a implementação que falei é só para não ficar fazendo tantas verificações

Comment: Leandro aqui no dispositivo físico normal

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72541/discussion-between-andersoncanteiro-and-leandro-araujo).

Comment: Ok, Vamos ir para o chat

Comment: Pra concluir, o problema estava no meu Android Studio. Ao testar em outra máquina o app executou normalmente.